# My millisecond stopwatch seems to be slow

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

I was bored so I wrote a quick millisecond stopwatch program in C++, but I noticed it was slower than it should be; that being the data seemed behind actual time.
Here's a look at my simple code. I assume the console clearing method and/or the delay is slowing it down, but I am not sure of a solution to speed up the program for an accurate time reading.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread; // sleep_for, sleep_until
using namespace std::chrono; // nanoseconds, system_clock, 
seconds

void DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS(int millisec) {
    sleep_until(system_clock::now() + milliseconds (millisec));
}
void clearConsole()
{
    system( "CLS");
}
struct Time {
    unsigned int tick = 0;
    unsigned int millisec = 0;
    unsigned int sec = 0;
    unsigned int min = 0;
    unsigned int hr = 0;
    unsigned int days = 0;
} timeAm;

int main()
{
    cout << "Started stopwatch" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        //listens if user presses stop key
        //stop key is ESC
        //This should also write the time to a textFile

        if (GetKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)
        {
            ofstream File("time.txt");
            File << "[" << timeAm.hr << " Hours] "
                 << "[" << timeAm.hr << " Minutes]"
                 << "[" << timeAm.min << " Seconds]"
                 << "[" << timeAm.sec << " Milliseconds]";
            File.close();
            return 0;
        }
        DELAY_IN_MILLISECONDS(1); //1 second delay
        //seconds
        timeAm.millisec++;
        //minutes
        if (timeAm.millisec > 59)
        {
            timeAm.millisec = 0;
            timeAm.sec++;
        }
        //hours
        if (timeAm.sec > 59)
        {
            timeAm.sec = 0;
            timeAm.min++;
        }
        //days
        if (timeAm.min > 23)
        {
            timeAm.min = 0;
            timeAm.hr++;
        }
        clearConsole(); //clears console
        //prints to console
        cout << "[" << timeAm.hr << " Hours] "
             << "[" << timeAm.hr << " Minutes]"
             << "[" << timeAm.min << " Seconds]"
             << "[" << timeAm.sec << " Milliseconds]";
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until : _"The function also may block for longer than `until` after `sleep_time` has been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays."_

Comment: For better accuracy, you should store a `time_point` when your stopwatch begins, and advance that to the next millisecond beyond `now`. You might skip some, depending on your display routines. You should always time from an actual reference, so in addition to this you must subtract `now` from your initial `time_point` in order to determine the total elapsed time.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with either function. Commenting out one function and leaving the other still causes a slow clock. Disabling both functions speeds up the process. I would like a way to have these functions while also having an accurate clock if possible.

Comment: Why are you advancing your second counter after 59 milliseconds? There are 1000 milliseconds in a second.

Comment: Bear in mind that you are also writing to file and updating your console on the same thread as your millisecond calculator. This takes time. So you are actually delaying the clock three times: 1. to write to file, 2. to sleep, 3. to update the console. To have any hope of accuracy, you need to keep the stopwatch timer on a thread that does nothing else and update the file and the console periodically from the data on that thread. As long as you aren't writing from any other thread you don't need to worry about deadlock and race conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Your timer makes some incorrect assumptions:

1. *(incorrect)* Every sleep will be precisely 1ms

   As described in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until

   > The function also may block for longer than `until` after `sleep_time` has been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays.
2. *(incorrect)* All other code is executed instantly (takes exactly zero time).

   Obviously that's a crazy notion. But yet your code at present relies on it. It will sleep for 1ms (which as per above we already know might not be actually 1ms), and then increment its millisecond count. Following that, it does some computation and some I/O before getting back around to the top of the loop to sleep for another "1ms".

   By very definition, if the code between sleeps takes any time whatsoever then your clock will drift.
3. *(incorrect)* [system_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) is monotonic

   The documentation explicitly states it is not (*i.e.* the clock can be adjusted at any point in time). For a monotonic clock designed for this kind of thing, use [std::steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) instead.

So, what approach should you take?

The way timing normally works is you begin with a `time_point` and then at any time you calculate the time elapsed between then and now. With some basic math, you can then turn that into `HH:MM:SS.mmm`.

Doing it like this will deal with those first two incorrect assumptions. Whenever your process wakes up you can calculate the true elapsed time, independent of how long the other code (or the sleep) took.

Roll that all together, and you can do something like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    std::cout << std::setfill('0');

    auto tbegin = Clock::now();
    unsigned long elapsedMilli = -1U;
   
    do {
        Clock::duration elapsed = Clock::now() - tbegin;
        unsigned long ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(elapsed).count();
        if (elapsedMilli == ms)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(tbegin + milliseconds(ms + 1));
            continue;
        }
        elapsedMilli = ms;

        // Build time
        unsigned int t_millisec = ms % 1000; ms /= 1000;
        unsigned int t_sec = ms % 60; ms /= 60;
        unsigned int t_min = ms % 60; ms /= 60;
        unsigned int t_hr = ms % 24; ms /= 24;
        //unsigned int t_days = ms;

        // Display time
        std::cout << "["
             << std::setw(2) << t_hr << ":"
             << std::setw(2) << t_min << ":"
             << std::setw(2) << t_sec << "."
             << std::setw(3) << t_millisec << "]\n";

    } while (elapsedMilli < 5000);
}
```

Live demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/fzGbvx1sa

Comment: Very nice answer. Only thought is `5000` is more than adequate, and maybe something like `200` would be sufficient `:)`. Or with `#include <string>` maybe use `int (int argc, char **argv)` and `size_t tend = argc > 1 ? std::stol (argv[1]) : 200;` (`try` / `catch` intentionally omitted with `stol()`) with a final `while (elapsedMilli < tend);`

Comment: Fair point about accepting the value as a command-line argument. The value of 5000 was so if OP runs this at home, they'll at least see something happen before they go and modify it to run until keypress or whatever. I probably didn't need to leave that value so high for the poor old godbolt machines though.

Comment: I was chuckling when I ran it, because my xterm is usually blisteringly fast, but after about 3 sec, it gave up keeping the current prompt line at the bottom of the display window and output the rest below where it stopped `:)` Using `./stopwatch 10` or `200` the terminal has no problem.

Comment: Aww poor old xterm. I guess it has a certain tolerance for scrolling with output, and after enough overflow it just gives up. You should definitely output every microsecond instead ;)

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! I realize my assuming calculations were all done instantaneously was incorrect, but did not know of an accurate way to calculate the timed "delay" in order to produce a correct time. Thank you for walking through the process and the example!